# Unable to bind AD admin using passport-ldapauth

Tags: node.js, express, active-directory, passport.js

When attempting to configure passport-ldapauth and testing authentication, I get the following error:

```
lde_message: "000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907C2, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580"
```

I assume this is because anonymous bind is not allowed and I have provided the admin account credentials to passport-ldapauth's options...

```
/* /src/app.ts */

import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as uuid from 'uuid/v4';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import * as ldapAuthStrategy from 'passport-ldapauth'
const OPTS: ldapAuthStrategy.Options = {
  server: {
    url: process.env.AUTH_LDAP_URL,
    bindDN: process.env.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER_DN,
    bindCredentials: process.env.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASS,
    searchBase: "DC=example,DC=com,DC=us",
    searchFilter: "(sAMAccountName={{username}})"
  }
}
passport.use(new ldapAuthStrategy(OPTS));
```

My env file look something like this...

```
AUTH_LDAP_URL='ldap://X.X.X.X:389'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER_DN='cn=Administrator,dc=example,dc=com,dc=us'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
```

In a route, I have asked for authentication to occur, this is where the error is emitted...

```
/* /src/routes/login/index.ts */
import * as express from 'express';
import * as passport from 'passport';
const Router = express.Router();

Router.get('/AD/', (req, res)=>{
  res.render('login/login', {req: req, title: 'Login'});
}).post('/AD/go',  (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction): void | Response => {
  passport.authenticate('ldapauth', (err, user, info): void => {
    var error = err || info
    if (error){
      res.status(500).json({ status: 500, data: error })
    }else if (!user){
      res.status(401).json({ status: 404, data: "User Not Found" })
    }else{
      res.status(500).json({ status: 200, data: user })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
});

module.exports = Router;
```

I've spent the last 7 hours reading docs and trying to find examples online to help shine light on this issue. Some values have been modified to redact data. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This works if I use ldapsearch (again, redacted)

```
ldapsearch -b "dc=example,dc=com,dc=us" -H ldap://X.X.X.X:389 -x -D "cn=Administrator,dc=example,dc=com,dc=us" -W '(sAMAccountName=testuser)'
```

```
...
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue was the envvars were mistyped. 
`AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASS` should have been `AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

Your usage looks right, so maybe go through your settings and verify everything is right.

- Is `AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER_DN` actually correct? I know you probably changed this for the question, but the DN you show puts the user at the root of the domain, which probably isn't the case. Make sure you have pulled that value from the `distinguishedName` attribute of the user.
- Of course, check the password.
- Can your web server actually connect to port 389 of the LDAP server? How you test that depends on which OS your server is running. I'll often use the telnet client from the command line: `telnet X.X.X.X 389`

Comment: Here's the trick, I can use ldapsearch to bind with the admin account and search just fine. and the system I'm doing dev on can talk to said AD with 0 issues.